# call to beautiful.at_screen_connect() error in rc.lua

Tags: awesome-wm

I have been trying to configure the [awesome-copycats theme](https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats) package and keep getting the following error on startup:

```
<home>/.config/awesome/rc.lua:214: attempt to call a nil value (field 'at_screen_connect')
```

This refers to line 214 of the default rc.lua included with the theme package:
    awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen(function(s) beautiful.at_screen_connect(s) end)

My knowledge of the awesome api is limited, so even a small hint about this problem would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was already reported a couple of times upstream. As far as I see, no solution was seen yet, but I wanted to let you know that this is not "just you":

See https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats/issues/198 and
https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats/issues/226